# Web Share API level 2 DOMException: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, domexception

I am fetching an img, turning it into a file, and then trying to share that file. I tested the code on latest Chrome on Android (the only browser to currently support this API).

```
  if (shareimg && navigator.canShare) {
    share = async function() {
      const response = await fetch(shareimg);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const file = await new File([blob], "image.jpeg");

      navigator.share({
        url: shareurl,
        title: sharetitle,
        text: sharetext,
        files: [file]
      });
    };
  }
```

I am running the function in response to a user clicking a button (the share() method must be called from a user gesture, otherwise it won't work).

(I am testing this code using Browserstack, which provides a console for javascript errors, as I couldn't successfully link my Android device to my mac for debugging and this API only works on mobile phones - not on Chrome for desktop.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code can be optimized a bit. It is currently necessary to specify the MIME type of the blob. You can check the code below out in practice here: https://statuesque-backpack.glitch.me/.

```js
if ('canShare' in navigator) {
  const share = async function(shareimg, shareurl, sharetitle, sharetext) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(shareimg);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const file = new File([blob], 'rick.jpg', {type: blob.type});

      await navigator.share({
        url: shareurl,
        title: sharetitle,
        text: sharetext,
        files: [file]
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.name, err.message);
    }
  };

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    share(
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Rick_Astley_Dallas.jpg/267px-Rick_Astley_Dallas.jpg',
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Astley',
      'Rick Astley',
      'Never gonna give you up!'
    );
  });  
}
```

Comment: Still not working... What could be the problem?

Comment: What kind of error message do you get? What file are you trying to share? Maybe it's in a format that isn't supported?

Comment: Been working on this issue for 6 hours now.. until I found this. It works great, thank you.

Comment: @mohamadb maybe due to file extension. replace these line `const file = new File([blob], 'rick.jpg', {type: blob.type});` with thse 2 lines `const ext = shareimg.split('.').pop();
          const file = new File([blob], 'image.'+ext, {type: blob.type});`