# navigator.share() not working in HTTPS and in a supported browser

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception, web-share

I don't understand why [`navigator.share()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) is giving me an error even though my website meets all of the requirements listed on MDN (has HTTPS and supported by the browser).

The following code gives an error when I click the button:

[image: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied]

```js
shareScoreBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!(navigator.canShare && navigator.share))
  {
    console.log('This browser does not support sharing');
    showPopup('Error', 'This browser doesn\'t support sharing');
    return;
  }

  const toShare = {
    text: 'Check out my score in Perfectly Balanced!',
    url: 'https://pb.luisafk.repl.co',
    files: [
      new File([
        deathScreenshots[0]
      ], 'perfectly-balanced-score.png')
    ]
  };

  if (navigator.canShare(toShare))
  {
    navigator.share(toShare).then(() => {
      console.log('Shared death screenshots');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('Error sharing death screenshots:', err);
    });
  }
  else
  {
    delete toShare.files;
    toShare.text = `I got a score of ${score} in Perfectly Balanced!`;

    if (navigator.canShare(toShare))
    {
      navigator.share(toShare).then(() => {
        console.log('Shared score text');
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error('Error sharing score text:', err);
      });
    }
    else
    {
      showPopup('Error', 'Your browser doesn\'t support sharing');
      console.log('This browser does not support sharing the deathScreenshots or text');
    }
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

The website is served over HTTPS and my browser supports the Web Share API according to Mozilla and I also checked in the console `!!(navigator.canShare && navigator.share)`

Doesn't work on Windows 10 or Chrome on Android.

**EDIT:** <s>it says `(in promise)` but the only promise made in that code is by `navigator.share()` which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#exceptions) can't reject with a `DOMException` so I don't really know what's happening.</s> If I use `canShare` and `share` in the console it works fine...

**EDIT:** Many people misunderstood the question, so I will clarify it. My question is **what is causing `navigator.share()` to error?**

Comment: The function returns a promise. If you want to catch the error you will have to call `navigator.share(...).catch(err => { /* do something with the error */ })`. This is asynchronous, if you don't know about promises yet it's probably a good time to read up about them

Comment: Regarding "which according to MDN can't reject with a DOMException": if I'm not mistaken, it explicitly says that it throws DOMExceptions

Comment: @A_A Catching the errors with `.catch()` gives the same error (obviously) and, yes my bad, I didn't see the part about it throwing DOMExceptions, sorry. But I still don't know what's causing the error...

Comment: @LuisAFK please edit your question appropriately, I answered the question asked, I'm not thrilled I wasted my time answering the wrong one...

Comment: @JaredSmith Ok sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58767177/15584743)

You must specify the MIME type of the blobs to the `new File` constructor as follows:

`new File([ blob ], 'filename.png', { type: blob.type })`

Answer (score 0):

I think that every time you're calling `navigator.share()` you need to call it with the `await` operator, like this:

```
await navigator.share();
```

Otherwise any exceptions raised inside the promise returned by `navigator.share()` will not be caught by your `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking. What I'm asking is _why_ `navigator.share()` is giving an error. I already said that I get the same error using `.catch()` but I will update my code for it to be clearer.